# how to set value to Models and it's Sub Models in C#?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-web-api

I have Main Model class as Bellow

```
  public class MainModel
    {
        public string Code{ get; set; }
        public string FullName{ get; set; }
        public string Position{ get; set; }
        public virtual SUB_DETAILS subdetails { get; set; }
    }
```

and SUB_DETAILS Model class is:

```
public class SUB_DETAILS
    {
        public SUB_DETAILS()
        {
            MainModel= new HashSet<MainModel>();
        }
      public string UniqueCode { get; set; }
      public string PassportNumber { get; set; }
     public virtual ICollection<MainModel> MainModel{ get; set; }
    }
```

I want to set values to these models to send data to Web API myCode is:

```
MainModel r = new MainModel();
 r.Code= "1245454354";
 r.FullName= "FullName Here";
 r.Position="Position Here";
 r.subdetails.UniqueCode="151221";
 r.subdetails.PassportNumber="2145";
var sendData = client.PostAsJsonAsync("api/PostData", new List<MainModel> { r }).Result;
```

it doest not accept value for `r.subdetails.UniqueCode="151221";` and `r.subdetails.PassportNumber="2145";`
and give me the Error "Object reference not set to an instance of an object. MainModel.subdetails.get return null" can anyone help how to set value for my MainModel and it's SUB_DETAILS to send Correct data to Web API

Comment: You need to create an instance of SUB_DETAILS. Your subdetails  properties is null at first(the default for classes/referencetypes). One way of doing is the way you did it already for the MainModel property in SUB_DETAILS. There would have been the same problem if you hadn't created an instance for that property beforehand.

Comment: @Ralf Where should I create the Instance and how to Initialize it can you Write a sample code for me

Comment: @Ralf Where should I create the Instance and how to Initialize it can you Write a sample code for me

Comment: No i can't. I showed you already in your code how such thing can be done. Its already in there. The MainModel property in SUB_DETAILS. Just apply the same pattern.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it's wrong
You can change this

```
SUB_DETAILS s = new SUB_DETAILS();
        s.MainModel.Add(
            new MainModel
            {
                Code = "1245454354",
                FullName = "FullName Here",
                Position = "Position Here"
            }
        );
        s.UniqueCode = "151221";
       s.PassportNumber = "2145";
        var sendData = client.PostAsJsonAsync("api/PostData", new List<SUB_DETAILS> { s }).Result;






public class MainModel
{
    public string Code { get; set; }
    public string FullName { get; set; }
    public string Position { get; set; }
}



public class SUB_DETAILS
{
    public SUB_DETAILS()
    {
        MainModel = new HashSet<MainModel>();
    }
    public string UniqueCode { get; set; }
    public string PassportNumber { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<MainModel> MainModel { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: What's wrong? How does this relate to the other answer you posted? Ideally, you should only post one answer, unless you have two _substantially_ different approaches. Without an explanation, however, it's really hard to recognize what you're proposing. Can you [edit] your answer to explain your code, and contrast it to your other answer?

Comment: In this question we have two models - MainModel, SUB_DETAILS
But with this code we do not know which is the original model - so I decided to write in two ways

Answer (score 0):

Or

```
MainModel r = new MainModel();
        r.Code = "1245454354";
        r.FullName = "FullName Here";
        r.Position = "Position Here";
        r.SUB_DETAILS.Add(new SUB_DETAILS
        {
            UniqueCode = "151221",
            PassportNumber= "2145"
        }); 
        var sendData = client.PostAsJsonAsync("api/PostData", new List<MainModel> { r }).Result;

public class MainModel
{
    public MainModel()
    {
        SUB_DETAILS = new HashSet<SUB_DETAILS>();
    }
    public string Code { get; set; }
    public string FullName { get; set; }
    public string Position { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<SUB_DETAILS> SUB_DETAILS { get; set; }
}
 public class SUB_DETAILS
{
    public string UniqueCode { get; set; }
    public string PassportNumber { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: How does this relate to the other answer you posted? Ideally, you should only post one answer, unless you have two substantially different approaches. Without an explanation, however, it's really hard to recognize what you're proposing. Can you [edit] your answer to explain your code, and contrast it to your other answer?

Comment: In this question we have two models - MainModel, SUB_DETAILS
But with this code we do not know which is the original model - so I decided to write in two ways